# Add Checkbox Column into GridControlEx

Tags: c#, checkbox, grid

What I want to do is to add a column that filled by checkboxes and placed on the left side of the grid. The grid rows is binding from a query. I have this code:

```
string query = "SELECT TransID, Company, Period, EmpID, Employee FROM Trx"
DataTable tblClaim;
tblClaim = DB.sql.Select(query);
tblClaim.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(bool)); //I want this column placed on the left side of the grid
gcxClaim.ExGridControl.DataSource = tblClaim;
```

What I get from that code is, the checkbox is disabled and the column is placed on the right side. While I tried to place `tblClaim.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(bool));` before `tblClaim = DB.sql.Select(query);`, it got error. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @PawanNogariya: There is no error, but I got the wrong expected result. The checkbox is disabled and placed on the right side.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by below code:

```
string query = "SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Process, TransID, Company, Period, EmpID, Employee FROM Trx"

tblClaim = DB.sql.Select(query);
gcxClaim.ExGridControl.DataSource = tblClaim;
gcxClaim.ExGridView.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
for (int i = 0; i < tblClaim.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    gcxClaim.ExGridView.Columns[i].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
}
gcxClaim.ExGridView.Columns["Process"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
tblClaim.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(bool)).SetOrdinal(0);
```

This will set the index of column "Process" to 0

Comment: Where are you adding checkbox? Post the code where you are adding checkboxes

Comment: `tblClaim.Columns.Add("Process", typeof(bool)).SetOrdinal(0);`, this code is adding a checkbox on a column. `typeof(bool)` is to set a checkbox.

Comment: What!! I don't think so, it is just adding column to the datatable, you must be having some code in your aspx page that will be doing this. I need to see your grid gcxClaim code in your aspx page, post that part of your aspx page

Comment: The data on gcxClaim is binded from tblClaim's Datatable. And the checkbox is assigned on tblClaim just by using that code.

Comment: It's desktop app using C# btw, not aspx.. >O<

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27806/discussion-between-pawan-nogariya-and-mrjimoy-05)